# Time format as part of the archive zip filename

Tags: tfs, devops

I have a build definition which includes the Archive step and I want to name the archive file using the following date format:

```
$(Date:yyyyMMdd).zip
```

However the build doesn't replace the filename with the date instead it creates a file called

```
$(Date
```

Is there a way to specify a time format for the zip file in the Archive step?

Comment: However build variables such as $(Build.BuildNumber) do work and can be part of the filename. But using date is not working with the specified format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the `$(Date:yyyyMMdd)` in the Archive step becuase the `$(Date:yyyyMMdd)` is a [token](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/general#tokens) for Build number format, not a [variable](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/general#variables).

You have 2 options:

1. Like you said, put it in the build number and use the `$(Build.BuildNumber)`.
2. Add a PowerShell task with this script (you can use inline) before the Archive task:

   ```
   $date=$(Get-Date -Format g);
   Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=currentDate]$date"
   ```

   And in the Archive task use the variable `$(currentDate)`.